# How can I determine why my test method fails?

Tags: unit-testing, assertions, vs-unit-testing-framework, create-directory, test-explorer

This method works (it creates a directory with the string passed in):

```
internal static void ConditionallyCreateDirectory(string dirName)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
}
```

...but, in accord with my OCDish tendencies, I'm testing *all* methods "just in case"; I've got this test for it in my test project:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConditionallyCreateDirectory()
{
    string testDirName = "testDir";
    RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory(testDirName);
    bool dirCreated = System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format("C:\\{0}", testDirName));
    // also tried @"C:\{0}" and @"C:\\{0}"
    Assert.IsTrue(dirCreated);
}
```

But it fails; dirCreated is not true. Why? I can't (apparently) step into the method to see what exactly is happening, and the "Failed" message tells me nothing other than "Assert.IsTrue failed":

[image]

Why would this fail (fish), and how can I determine why it's failing (teach to fish)?

### UPDATE

I've also now tried each of the following:

```
bool dirCreated = System.IO.Directory.Exists(string.Format("C:\\{0}", testDirName));
bool dirCreated = System.IO.Directory.Exists(string.Format(@"C:\{0}", testDirName));
bool dirCreated = System.IO.Directory.Exists(string.Format(@"C:\\{0}", testDirName));
```

Comment: Looks to me like your input is invalid: You'll have to pass `"C:\\testDir"` into your method ... i.e. `string testDirName = "C:\\testDir";` (and assert accordingly).

Comment: Arggh, yes, you're right!

Comment: ... and concerning the "teach to fish": Clicking on your failed test should show the exception thrown by `Directory.CreateDirectory("testDir");` as the cause for your failed test. To my astonishment I could not find historical test results in my solutions "TestResults" folder - VS2012 just keeps all the folder it creates there but throws away the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConditionallyCreateDirectory()
{
    string testDirName = "C:\\testDir";
    RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.ConditionallyCreateDirectory(testDirName);
    bool dirCreated = System.IO.Directory.Exists(testDirName);
    Assert.IsTrue(dirCreated);
}
```